# vue.js javascript file from static folder

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, donut-chart

It is the first web application I am going to make, so I am totally new to Vue.js Javascript programming. I am using one of Boostrap templates called Beagle.

http://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=1696&show_new=

I have a file app-charts-morris.js which I hold in my Static folder, here is some code of this file:

```
var App = (function () {
'use strict';

App.chartsMorris = function( ){

  //Donut Chart
  function donut_chart(){
    var color1 = App.color.warning;
  var color2 = App.color.success;
  var color3 = App.color.primary;

  Morris.Donut({
        element: 'donut-chart',
        data: [
          {label: 'Facebook', value: 33 },
          {label: 'Google', value: 33 },
          {label: 'Twitter', value: 33}
        ],
        colors:[color1, color2, color3],
        formatter: function (y) { return y + "%" }
      });
  }

  donut_chart();

};

return App;
})(App || {});
```

What it does is it should show me Donut chart with some javascript functions, but nothing appears here only empty space.

Here is my Vue code:

```
<template>
<div id="donut-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data () {
  return {
  }
},
computed: {
},
watch: {
},
methods: {
}
}
</script>
```

and here where I access my javascript file:

```
 <script src="/static/js/app-charts-morris.js" type="text/javascript"> 
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //initialize the javascript
 App.init()
 App.chartsMorris()
 App.ChartJs()
 App.dashboard()
 });
</script>
```

my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import App from './App'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store'
import {VueMasonryPlugin} from 'vue-masonry'
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch'

Vue.use(InstantSearch)
Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueMasonryPlugin)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

 new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router,
 store,
 render: h => h(App),
 created () {
  }
  })
```

What is the problem here? Why vue.js does not show my Donut chart? But it shows without any framework

Comment: where your Vue instance is initialized (`new Vue({...})`) ?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

> *Here is my Vue code:*

If it's your `App.vue` file, as you initialize your Vue instance on an element `#app`, you need to add it in your template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="donut-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Or change the element to `donut-chart`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#donut-chart',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="donut-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
</template>
```